# Mark as secure an HTTP site on Chrome locally on my PC

Tags: google-chrome, browser, http, https

I want to mark permanently my HTTP site as secure on Chrome locally on my PC. I tried to add my site on browser's trusted sites but Chrome continues to mark it as not secure. I tried to use chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure but when I close and restart the browser, Chrome mark my site as unsafe again. Any suggestion?

Comment: As far as I can tell from this https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=441605#c67 , you also need to change the user-data-dir flag to a different directory.